# How to customize matplotlib plots using gcf() or gca()?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, deep-learning, customization, shap

I am using a package called `shap` which has a integrated plot function. However i want to adjust some things like the labels, legend, coloring, size etc.

[apparently due to the developer thats possible](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/247) via using plt.gcf().

I call the plot like this, this will give a figure object but i am not sure how to use it:

```
fig = shap.summary_plot(shap_values_DT, data_train,color=plt.get_cmap("tab10"), show=False)
ax = plt.subplot()
```

[image]

**UPDATE / SOLUTION**
Finally i got everything adjusted as i wanted it by doing the following:

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values_DT, data_train, color=plt.get_cmap("tab10"), show=False)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_figheight(12)
fig.set_figwidth(14)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlabel(r'durchschnittliche SHAP Werte $\vert\sigma_{ij}\vert$', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel('Inputparameter', fontsize=16)
ylabels = string_latexer([tick.get_text() for tick in ax.get_yticklabels()])
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels)
leg = ax.legend()
for l in leg.get_texts(): l.set_text(l.get_text().replace('Class', 'Klasse'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's `ax=plt.gca()`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks, with that I got the most things working, the last piece missing, is the legend colorings, which is shifted by 1 color if i change the legend labels.. do you have an idea what's causing this?

Comment: No, from the pictures you show I do not see any shift, so I may not understand what problem there is.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it's already solved, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally i got everything adjusted as i wanted it by doing the following:

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values_DT, data_train, color=plt.get_cmap("tab10"), show=False)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_figheight(12)
fig.set_figwidth(14)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlabel(r'durchschnittliche SHAP Werte $\vert\sigma_{ij}\vert$', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel('Inputparameter', fontsize=16)
ylabels = string_latexer([tick.get_text() for tick in ax.get_yticklabels()])
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels)
leg = ax.legend()
for l in leg.get_texts(): l.set_text(l.get_text().replace('Class', 'Klasse'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have not used `shap` yet, but maybe you can modify in the following way:

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values_DT, data_train,color=plt.get_cmap("tab10"), show=False)
plt.title('my custom title')
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

**Update**
From the official documentation, I read

```py
import xgboost
import shap

# load JS visualization code to notebook
shap.initjs()

# train XGBoost model
X,y = shap.datasets.boston()
model = xgboost.train({"learning_rate": 0.01}, xgboost.DMatrix(X, label=y), 100)

# explain the model's predictions using SHAP values
# (same syntax works for LightGBM, CatBoost, and scikit-learn models)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)

# visualize the first prediction's explanation (use matplotlib=True to avoid Javascript)
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], X.iloc[0,:])
```

I quickly tried the example and it seems to work, if you add the `matplotlib=True` option. Nevertheless, not all functions seem to support it...

Comment: Thanks for the input, i got some things working already, however i am mostly concerned with `summary_plot()` function which has no matplotlib=True option. I will add some details about my progress and what's left to do to the question